# maintaining slider position in xcode when switching views

Tags: ios, xcode, slider

I'm very new to objective c (three weeks) and also in my 70s so not as quick as I used to be! Anyway, I'm doing okay with an app for IOS except for a problem with maintaining slider position and value when switching away from a view and back again. To clarify: I have 3 views, each with 4 sliders and I want to be able to return to any view with the sliders positions and values the same as they were left. I'm sure there's a way of doing this but I've searched all over to no avail so I hope someone here can help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the "How to Ask" page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question to help the volunteers help you. At a minimum, a code sample of your ViewController implementation and headers would be useful, since you'd have to maintain state somewhere in there.

Comment: Ah, sorry, Palpatim. I hadn't included it because i have nothing other than the slider code itself. I didn't know how to find what I need to use so all I have is this in my header file: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *practicalSlider; (which is similar for all the sliders) and this in my implementation file: - (IBAction)practical:(id)sender
{
    int practVariable=(int) (_practicalSlider.value);
    pVariable=practVariable;
    [self transmissions];
}

Comment: For the benefit of other newbies to programming objective C who might have the same problem, I thought I'd post the code here:  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[_imageSlider value] forKey:@"isliderValue"]; goes into the slider method, and: [_imageSlider setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"isliderValue"]]; goes in 'viewWillAppear'

Answer (score 0):

Do you allocate an instance of a viewController every time you push it onto your navigation stack ?  if so , create a property and allocate it only once and use the same object to push in onto your navigation stack. it should retain the position.

Another possible solution is to persist the current value of the slider in your viewController and set the slider value to the persisted value in viewWillAppear , which gets called every time the view comes on screen

Comment: Thank you NavinDev - I shall work out what that means (not being sarcastic - just dim at the moment!) and try to use either solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the sliders values using something like NSUserDefaults. Look it up for more info.

Comment: Thank you Nas5296 - I shall investigate.

Comment: Yeah anytime! I hope you figure it out!

Comment: Thank you Nas5296 - all sorted and working perfectly. Thank you for your suggestion!